# Is it possible two update two servers at once with AnkhSVN?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, version-control, collaboration, ankhsvn

I want my project to be backed up to two servers thru AnkhSVN.

I want that when I click "Commit" it should update two sources at once, is this possible?

Comment: For redundancy purposes?

Comment: @Sander, Yes. I want to have 2 copies of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with AnkhSVN, or any other client, because the working copy can be linked to just 1 repository at a time. You can however replicate a repository to another location, giving you the copy of everything. Have a look at [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnsync.html) and [Repository Replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) in the svnbook.

Comment: How do I use this svnsync? that's actually what I am looking for.

Comment: That's described in the link I provided: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication The story is too long to post here as an answer